# Spinner not loading data; log cat displays "Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed"

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

When the splash activity launches, the next acivity users login in. usernames and passwords are stored in mysql db. the link is properly establish but Enob_login activity
tells me to check my internet connection yet when i run the ipaddress
on my pc browser (http://192.168.1.11/EnoticeWeb/DB_Enob_Frame.php) i can view the json printout:

```
[{"0":"1","cnb_id":"1","1":"Admin","cnb_name":"Admin","2":"admin","cnb_pwd":"admin"},
{"0":"2","cnb_id":"2","1":"Hod","cnb_name":"Hod","2":"hod","cnb_pwd":"hod"},
{"0":"3","cnb_id":"3","1":"Staff","cnb_name":"Staff","2":"staff","cnb_pwd":"staff"},
{"0":"4","cnb_id":"4","1":"Student","cnb_name":"Student","2":"student","cnb_pwd":"student"}];
```

Please help me out!!!!!!!!!!

this is my NetConnection.java codes

```
public class NetConnection extends Activity {


   private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private String prefName = "report";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try {
        prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String net_ip=prefs.getString("ip", "http://192.168.1.11/enoticeweb/");

        URL url = new URL(net_ip);
        executeReq(url);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("connection", 1);
        editor.commit();

        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(NetConnection.this,Enob_Login.class));            
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Check Network Connection " +
                "and IP Address ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("connection", 0);
        editor.commit();

        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(NetConnection.this,Enob_Login.class));
    }
}

public void executeReq(URL urlObject) throws IOException {

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObject.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(30000);//milliseconds
    conn.setConnectTimeout(3500);//milliseconds
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setDoInput(true);

    // Start connect
    conn.connect();
    InputStream response =conn.getInputStream();
    Log.d("Response:", response.toString());
}
}
```

and my Enob_login.java codes

```
  public class Enob_Login extends Activity {

   Spinner Spinn_Frame;
    EditText Edit_Frame_Pwd;
    Button But_Go;

List<String> List_Frame, List_Frame_Pwd, List_cnbid;

String Str_Frame_Pwd, Str_Alert_Msg, Str_Alert_Title;
int Int_Frame_Pos;

InputStream is=null;
String result=null;
String line=null;

String IP_Address;

private SharedPreferences prefs;
private String prefName = "report";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.enob_login);

    prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
    int Conn_Check = prefs.getInt("connection", 100);

    if(Conn_Check == 0)
    {
    AlertDialog.Builder Alert_Conn_Error = new AlertDialog.Builder(Enob_Login.this);
    Alert_Conn_Error.setMessage("Check your Internet Connection..");
    Alert_Conn_Error.setTitle("Connection Error");
    Alert_Conn_Error.setPositiveButton("Ok", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        finish();
    }
    });

    Alert_Conn_Error.show();
    }
    else {

    initialise_variables();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String> 
    (this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, List_Frame);
    adp.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    Spinn_Frame.setAdapter(adp);
    Int_Frame_Pos = 0;
    Spinn_Frame.setSelection(Int_Frame_Pos);
    Str_Frame_Pwd = List_Frame_Pwd.get(Int_Frame_Pos).toString();

    Spinn_Frame.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Int_Frame_Pos = arg2;
        Str_Frame_Pwd = List_Frame_Pwd.get(Int_Frame_Pos).toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});

    But_Go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(Edit_Frame_Pwd.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

            Str_Alert_Msg = "Enter Password !!!";
            Str_Alert_Title = "Error";
            alert_method();
        }
        else {

            if(Edit_Frame_Pwd.getText().toString().equals(Str_Frame_Pwd)) {

                if(Int_Frame_Pos == 0) {

                    save();
                }
                if(Int_Frame_Pos == 1) {

                    save();
                }
                if(Int_Frame_Pos == 2) {

                    save();
                }
                if(Int_Frame_Pos == 3) {

                    save();
                }
            }
            else {
                Str_Alert_Msg = "Wrong Password !!!";
                Str_Alert_Title = "Error";
                alert_method();
            }
        }
    }

    private void save() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

        //---save the values in the EditText view to preferences---
        editor.putInt("cnb_id", 
            Integer.parseInt(List_cnbid.get(Int_Frame_Pos).toString()));

        //---saves the values---
        editor.commit();

        finish();

        Intent i = new Intent(Enob_Login.this, User_Login.class);
        startActivity(i);
        Edit_Frame_Pwd.setText(null);
    }
});   
    }
}

public void initialise_variables() {

    Spinn_Frame = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    Edit_Frame_Pwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    But_Go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    List_Frame = new ArrayList<String>();       
    List_Frame_Pwd = new ArrayList<String>();
    List_cnbid = new ArrayList<String>();

    prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
    IP_Address = prefs.getString("ip", "http://192.168.1.11/enoticeweb/");

    DB_Enob_Frame();
}

public void DB_Enob_Frame() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(IP_Address + "DB_Enob_Frame.php");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();             
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("DB_Enob_Frame", e.toString());
    }     

    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();         
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("DB_Enob_Frame", e.toString());
    }     

    try
    {
        JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(result);
        JSONObject jobj = null;

        for(int i=0; i<jarray.length(); i++) {

            jobj = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

            List_Frame.add(jobj.getString("cnb_name"));
            List_Frame_Pwd.add(jobj.getString("cnb_pwd"));
            List_cnbid.add(String.valueOf(jobj.getInt("cnb_id")));
        }

        prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

        editor.putString("ip", IP_Address);

        editor.commit();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("DB_Enob_Frame", e.toString());
    }
}

public void alert_method() {

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Enob_Login.this);
    alert.setMessage(Str_Alert_Msg);
    alert.setTitle(Str_Alert_Title);
    alert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
    alert.show();
    Edit_Frame_Pwd.setText(null);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    finish();       
}
}
```

Comment: try correcting your URL case on line `String net_ip=prefs.getString("ip", "http://192.168.1.11/enoticeweb/");`

Comment: by using that url, i can view my project hosted in wamp server in the browser